# Wallpaper flickers on external displays on 16.10

Tags: display, 16.10, external-monitor, flicker

After (re)installing 16.10, when using external displays with my laptop (Dell XPS13 9333), the wallpaper flickers in a weird way. When dragging windows around the desktop, they also leave a trail. All windows are rendered properly, and so are the icons on my desktop. Only the wallpaper has this issue. Sometimes it's only parts of the screen.

I've made [a video](https://blackfin.cannedtuna.org/wallpaper-flicker.mp4) of what it looks like.

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: unless it's a problem with my browser, I can't see that video

Comment: @MarkYisri, do you get a 404 or are you just not able to see it because of some codex problem?

Comment: I just can't see it. No 404

Answer (score 0):

I had also the same problem on my Thinkpad x230 and external Dell U2415 monitor. I tried different things, updating drivers, switching some settings but nothing really helps.

Try to install CompizConfig Settings Manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

and play with settings in **Workarounds** under **Unity category**. For me was helpful against any flickering - **Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint**.